# Using declaration for overloaded inherited function with private accessibility

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo(int arg) { foo(arg, false); }
private:
    void foo(int arg, bool flag) {}
};
```

It is built this way because I want `foo`'s flag argument to only be false when called from outside `A`. I want to inherit it privately, but allow calling `foo`:

```
class B : private A
{
public:
    using A::foo;
};
```

However, this fails because the using declaraion attempts to bring *all* the overloads of `foo` into scope, including the private one, which the the compiler rightly rejects.

This isn't hard to fix, I can either:

1. Change the accessibility of `A::foo(int, bool)` to protected or public
2. Inherit `A` publicly; only public overloads of `foo` will be inherited
3. Change the name of `A::foo(int, bool)` so that the using declaration does not attempt to bring it into scope

This is a small, private project, and besides, that overload is only called inside `A`. So fixing the problem is a non-issue here. (I'm just going to rename the private overload.)

But it doesn't feel like it should be necessary. Why does the using declaration attempt to bring the non-accessible methods into scope? Is this particular case just not covered by the standard? Is there a way to fix this besides the methods I listed?

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug... Which compiler are you using? Calling the private overload is rejected by GCC (both 5.5 and 8.1), which is what it *should* be, the private overload remaining private even with the using declaration.

Comment: @Aconcagua - It's not a bug. [All the members being introduced must be accessible](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#17) when being introduced.

Comment: Yes, I don't expect the using declaration to magically give access to the private overload. I just didn't expect it to *try* pulling the private overload into scope. I've tested this behavior with gcc, clang, and msvc. (On the online compiler Godbolt.) All compilers throw an error, so I'm assuming it's intended behavior.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ah, I thought so. I guess I just expected the using declaration to be a bit more subtle than that.

Comment: @StoryTeller Reading this section again and again, I come back: Sounds like a compiler bug - but not in the direction I thought first: If one of the overloads is not accessible, then already the using declaration itself should fail???

Comment: @StoryTeller And I am confirmed by subsequent paragraph 19!

Comment: @Aconcagua Both MSVC and Clang give pretty useful errors: "not all overloads are accessible", and "foo is a private member of A", respectively. Both pointing directly at the using declaration. GCC is less useful, giving "A::foo is private within this context", pointing at the `class B` line. So the compiler does fail appropriately.

Comment: @jpfx1342 Fine, so then no bug here... I read your question as "I did so and it worked".

Comment: @StoryTeller at this point I could argue that this is a standard flaw. In current situation we might want using declaration to gain access only to the accessible overloads and ignore inaccessible, otherwise they'll become inaccessible due to private inheritance. In large hierarchy there might be a chance that we accidentally hit same name as some private member in lower level. Or a retcon happens and such private member would appear. Imho, it should be a warning lest no accessible names is present at all. But yeah, in this case the only thing we can do is to redefine overload.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie - Your point is not without merit (and coincidentally, that's exactly how inheriting constructors work). But the wording for a using declaration of regular members predates that, and the only way to change it is with a compelling paper to the standards committee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also redefine the overload you want and have it forward its argument to the function in `A`:

```
class B : private A
{
public:
    void foo(int arg) { A::foo(arg); }
};
```

The using declaration is just too blunt a tool in this case. It brings function *names* into the derived class scope. And when the name refers to something private, it chokes. It can't distinguish overloads. The standard requires the names introduced by a using declaration to be accessible:

> [[namespace.udecl]/17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#17)
>
> In a using-declarator that does not name a constructor, all members of
>   the set of introduced declarations shall be accessible. In a
>   using-declarator that names a constructor, no access check is
>   performed. In particular, if a derived class uses a using-declarator
>   to access a member of a base class, the member name shall be
>   accessible. **If the name is that of an overloaded member function, then
>   all functions named shall be accessible.** The base class members
>   mentioned by a using-declarator shall be visible in the scope of at
>   least one of the direct base classes of the class where the
>   using-declarator is specified.

---

The forwarding function can also be templated. So one won't need to redefine each function they want to expose individually.

```
class B : private A
{
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    void foo(Args ...args) { A::foo(args...); }
};
```

It's "catch-all" like the using declaration, except the access specifier is checked only on template instantiation, i.e. when the function is called. So the template will be ill-formed based on its scope and whether or not the member in `A` is accessible there.

Comment: I suppose I hadn't considered that, though I'd prefer to not have to write functions like this when a `using` will do.

Comment: @jpfx1342 - That's the only way to selectively bring functions in. Like I said, a using declaration is for names. So it's always all the things named `foo`, or nothing.

Comment: @JeJo I'd just rather use a `using` declaration than redefine the function. I think it's cleaner, and clearer that it's the same function. Renaming it would only make things worse.

Comment: [namespace.udecl/19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#19) is even clearer about, see the example there. According to, even already the using declaration is illegal.

Comment: @Aconcagua - The declaration itself being illegal is p17, which I quoted. The example is indeed of that too.

Comment: @StoryTeller On the other hand, I think the standard us unnecessarily strict on the matter. What would speak against just importing the functions/variables visible at where the `using` appears? Different definition of "using", sure, but more pragmatic (at least for programmers). And as just weakening restrictions, wouldn't break any existing code...

Comment: @Aconcagua - That's exactly what the using declaration does. Access specifiers don't affect visibility. There are in fact very few contexts where names can be hidden in C++. For better or for worse, that's the language design we have.

Comment: @jpfx1342 - I had another option come to mind. Please read the new material in the answer. You can have your cake and eat it too, in a way.

Comment: @StoryTeller Hm, I seem to have badly expressed myself - I meant exactly the opposite, *legalising* the example in §19 (and the private overloads would remain private/inaccessible)... *Now*, it is *not*, I know, but it *could* be in next version of standard. Would anything speak against? I don't see anything...

Answer (score 3):

I found the following extract from Scott Meyer's Effective C++ which is related to your predicament (with emphasis added):

> **Item 33: Avoid hiding inherited names.**
>   ...
>   This means that if you inherit from a base class with overloaded functions
>   and you want to redefine or override only some of them, you need
>   to include a using declaration for each name you’d otherwise be hiding.
>   If you don’t, some of the names you’d like to inherit will be hidden.
>   ...
>
> It’s conceivable that you sometimes won’t want to inherit all the functions
>   from your base classes. Under public inheritance, this should
>   never be the case, because, again, it violates public inheritance’s is-a
>   relationship between base and derived classes. (That’s why the using
>   declarations above are in the public part of the derived class: names
>   that are public in a base class should also be public in a publicly
>   derived class.)
>
> **Under private inheritance, however, it can
>   make sense. For example, suppose Derived privately inherits from
>   Base, and the only version of the function that Derived wants to inherit is the
>   one taking no parameters. *A using declaration won’t do the trick here,
>   because a using declaration makes all inherited functions with a given
>   name visible in the derived class*.**
>   No, this is a case for a different technique, namely, a simple forwarding function:

```
class Base {
public:
   virtual void mf1() = 0;
   virtual void mf1(int);
... // as before
};
class Derived: private Base {
public:
   virtual void mf1() // forwarding function; implicitly
   { 
      Base::mf1(); } // inline 
   }; 
}
```